# My 2001 Honda Prelude

Tags: honda, starting, prelude

When I put the key in all the lights turned on and everything except it doesn't want to start and doesn't make no noise or nothing just nothing

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What have you tried to do? Have you measured the voltage at the battery? What lights are on on the dash? Is there one with a green key (might be blinking)?

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem with my Prelude from 83.

Its probably your car battery.

Get a multi-meter and measure the car battery.

keep the pins on the battery and then ask someone else to start the car.

If you see that the battery loses a significant amount of voltage/amperage it means the battery is dead.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!